# Is it possible to point to a helper or a concern method inside a link_to (Rails 4)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Is it possible to replace the standard link_to structure :

```
link_to "France", :controller => :static_pages, :action => :france
```

BY referring not to a controller but to a helper's method or a concern's method

```
 - link_to "France", :helper => :my_helper, :action => :method_name_inside_helper

 - link_to "France", :concern_module => :country_concern_module, :action => :method_name_inside_the_concern_module
```

Why would I like to do that: Indeed using a controller forces me to create ONE route per country and use redirects...I'd rather just use a helper or a concern module that do do force me to create a route when using one of their method.

Thanks!

Comment: create one action to accept all the requests and just pass the country name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**MVC**

The answer to this is that since Rails is built on the [MVC programming pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller), you have to adhere to certain "conventions which are present in this type of framework:

[image]

The bottom line here is that when you request a URL, what you're *really* doing is sending a request to Rails, which will then route the request to a particular controller action.

Helpers & concerns are there to provide extra functionality to the various *controller* actions that you serve.

> To answer your question - you need to use your routes to send a
>   request to your `controller`, which will then be able to pull data
>   from your `model`, showing in your `view`

--

**OOP**

A further explanation of this will come from [`object-orientated programming`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming), which Rails is very much built on.

Everything you do in Rails needs to revolve *around* objects. Each controller action, model call, view, link, etc, needs to involve `objects`. These allow you to create a system which advocates & facilitates the adaptation & manipulation of the various objects

Now, your question is whether you can "route directly to a helper method or concern". The answer here is "no", simply because that is not `object` orientated. It's `method` orientated

Ever wonder why Rails' routes are declared with [`resources`](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#resource-routing:-the-rails-default)?
[image]

It's because Rails entire system needs to be constructed *around* objects / resources. This means your controllers will be able to provide a central set of "CRUD" actions to support the manipulation of these objects for you

Answer (score 1):

**Short Ans:** No, you can't.

**Long Ans:**

You can't point links or URLs directly to helper or concerns. These are modules, they can't handle requests.

You will need to point to contoller's action first. In the action, you can call helper/concern methods and return result after processing.